# Why wont the changes in color I make in UV/image editor show in rendered images?

Tags: rendering, uv-image-editor

When attempting to change the color of a specific texture, a Minecraft leaf block to be precise. I wanted to change it from green to pink through the UV/image editor

[image: ImageEditor]

The color changed

[image: ColorChanged]

however when I, later on, tried to render an image the color was still green but it's pink in the normal view:

[image: WrongColor]

Is there something I need to enable to change the color in a rendered image? I'm in cycles render and the color of the texture resets itself if I close blender and reopen it, regardless of whether or not I saved my progress.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Can you please add an image of the node setup for the leaf materials?  Pink usually means that the texture is missing, not sure how it is normal in rendered view though.

Comment: Plain Magenta  is missing texture and it would be missing in both renders. Did you change the colors in Blender and not save the texture to a file, b4 render?